# how to add dataclasses requirement in poetry for python 3.9

Tags: python, dependencies, python-dataclasses, python-poetry

Trying out poetry here for maintaining dependencies. I cant seem to get dataclasses into it.

here is my toml file:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
certifi = "^2020.12.5"
chardet = "^4.0.0"
hivemind-util = "^0.1b35"
idna = "^2.9"
requests = "^2.25.1"
urllib3 = "^1.26.3"
pytest = "^6.2.2"
pandas = "^1.2.3"
pyarrow = "^3.0.0"
numpy = "^1.20.1"
pyodbc = "^4.0.30"
responses = "^0.12.1"
openpyxl = "^3.0.6"
SQLAlchemy = "^1.3.23"
dataclasses-json = "^0.5.2"
```

when i run

```
poetry add dataclasses
```

I get

```
 SolverProblemError

  The current project's Python requirement (>=2.7,<2.8 || >=3.4) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
    - dataclasses requires Python >=3.6, <3.7, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=2.7,<2.8 || >=3.4,<3.6 || >=3.7

  Because no versions of dataclasses match >0.8,<0.9
   and dataclasses (0.8) requires Python >=3.6, <3.7, dataclasses is forbidden.
  So, because my-project depends on dataclasses (^0.8), version solving failed.

  at ~\.poetry\lib\poetry\puzzle\solver.py:241 in _solve
      237│             packages = result.packages
      238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
      239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
      240│         except SolveFailure as e:
    → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
      242│
      243│         results = dict(
      244│             depth_first_search(
      245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties

    For dataclasses, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.6,<3.7"

    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies,
    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers
```

What is wrong here? Dataclasses are avialable for python 3.9

Comment: Are you sure, you are showing the extract from the correct `pyproject.toml`? You have `python = "^3.9"` but the error message is saying `The current project's Python requirement (>=2.7,<2.8 || >=3.4)`.

Comment: @finswimmer I'm having the same weird error with another package, python = "^3.9",The current project's Python requirement (3.6.5) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
    - fastapi-users requires Python >=3.7, so it will not be satisfied for Python 3.6.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dataclasses` module is part of the standard library of `python3.7` and later. You only need to install it if you want to support `python3.6` too (See also [the description](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/) on PyPI: "A **backport** of the dataclasses module for Python 3.6"). The error message tells you that, too, but in a way that is a little hard to understand if you're not a computer.

Given that your python version seems to be 3.9, you don't need to do anything - you can just use dataclasses.